# Change table data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hopefully this will be easy for this community. I am a bit of a beginner.
I am working on MS SQL server 2008
I need to transform some table data in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT Qty, WidgetNum, COLOR FROM wherever
```

I have table data like the following:

```
Qty | widgetnum       | COLOR
-----------------------------
2   | 100widget-TWO   | WHITE
1   | 200widget-THREE | BLACK
```

I need to transform it into the following table data:

```
Qty | widgetnum | COLOR
-----------------------------
4   | 100widget | WHITE
3   | 200widget | BLACK
```

I probably have 100 or so widget numbers to do this too and thousands of records in the table.
Thanks

Comment: Is the values of the widgetnum-column always on the form "xxxyyyyy-NNNNN" where NNNNN is "TWO", "THREE", etc.? And what other values for NNNNN are possible?

Comment: How did `2` and `1` become `4` and `3`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: 2 * TWO = 4, 1 * THREE = 3

Comment: No. The lengths of "xxxyyyy" vary but the widgetnum column are unique values. The -NNNNN will always be preceded with a dash (-) and there are only 4 total forms for -NNNNNNN. -TWO,-TW,-THREE,-THRE

Comment: Yes. It is the math as Dan says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE wherever
SET 
Qty=Qty*( CASE
            WHEN widgetnum like '%-TW' THEN 2
            WHEN widgetnum like '%-TWO' THEN 2
            WHEN widgetnum like '%-THREE' THEN 3
            WHEN widgetnum like '%-THRE' THEN 3
            ELSE 1 END),
widgetnum=(CASE 
             WHEN widgetnum like '%-TW' THEN REPLACE(widgetnum,'-TW','')
             WHEN widgetnum like '%-TWO' THEN REPLACE(widgetnum,'-TWO','')
             WHEN widgetnum like '%-THREE' THEN REPLACE(widgetnum,'-THREE','')
             WHEN widgetnum like '%-THRE' THEN REPLACE(widgetnum,'-THRE','')
             ELSE widgetnum END)
```

Comment: This code executes fine and appears to be what I want but all it seems to be doing is removing those items from the table.

Comment: Are you sure you are missing lines? The update queries do not remove lines.

Comment: I think there is a conflict with existing code. I am trying insert that code snippet inside an existing ELSE BEGIN / END

Comment: Yea. It isn't removing them from the table but they disappeared from the SELECT I had following the UPDATE. I was trying to first do the above UPDATE then do my SELECT but I am pretty sure I need to integrate it into my SELECT clause.

Comment: I got this working. Your code was fine it was my issue integrating it into my existing procedure. THANKS!